# In Spacemacs, how can I conditionally set line-wrapping on only for text files (i.e. in text mode)?

Tags: spacemacs, text-editing, wrapping, configuration-files

I want to have Spacemacs wrap around long lines, but only in text files (i.e. text mode), not in programming language files (i.e. program mode).

How could one achieve that? I know that to turn on line-wrapping one could simply include this in the user-config:

```
(setq toggle-word-wrap)
```

To turn it on only for text files, I tried:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'toggle-word-wrap)
```

But it did not work. How could I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `dotspacemacs/user-config`:

```
(defun my/enable-word-wrap ()
  (setq-local word-wrap t))
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'my/enable-word-wrap)
```

That works for me, for example, if I open a new file with `SPC f f` and then `SPC SPC text-mode`.

`toggle-word-wrap` is an interactive *command* (not merely a non-interactive *function*) that does as it says: *toggles* word wrap, not really ideal for programmatic use.